# Relationship: category need article_id

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, relationship

I want to create relationship `one to many`. So I have table article with `"articlescategory_id"` column. I have table `articlescategories` too.
My relationships look like this

```
public function articles(){
      return $this->hasMany('App\Article');
 }
public function category(){
      return $this->hasOne('App\Articlescategory');
 }
```

It should works correctly but I have the error

> "Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
>   'articlescategories.article_id'". Column "articlescategory_id" points
>   on category

Comment: show your table and put your both model code too.

Answer (score 1):

one to many inverse code is `belongsTo` not `hasOne`

Main difference:

belongsTo and belongsToMany you're telling Laravel that this table holds the foreign key that connects it to the other table

hasOne and hasMany is telling Laravel that this table does not have the foreign key

change your code:

```
public function category(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Articlescategory');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, add directly your foreign key to your relations ship. and change `hasOne` into `belongsTo`

```
public function category(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Articlescategory', 'your_foreign_key_here');
}
```

e.g

```
public function category(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Articlescategory', 'articlescategory_id');
}
```